# View php session variables

Tags: php, firefox, google-chrome, browser, session-variables

Not sure if this belongs here or at webapps... please move if appropriate.

I don't even know if such a thing is possible, but is there an extension or add-on for either Firefox or Chrome that would let me view all my PHP session variables the way there are extensions that let you view cookies?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Cookies are available on the client-side, so they can be seen from the browser.

On the other hand, **session data is stored on the server**, and never sent to the client *(except you write some code to do just that, of course)*.

To dump the content of a variable, like `$_SESSION`, you can use the [**`var_dump()`**](https://www.php.net/var_dump) function.

On a development server, you can install the [**Xdebug**](http://xdebug.org/) extension to enhance its output greatly *(and lots of other debugging-related things, btw)*.

If you don't want to pollute the HTML of your page, you could install the [**FirePHP**](http://www.firephp.org/) extension to FireBug, and use the corresponding PHP library to send data *(like dump of variables)* to it.

This would allow your variables, like `$_SESSION`, to be displayed in firebug's console.

Comment: I accepted this a while ago but never commented. The FirePHP extension was what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: That means the user or hackers has no way to see what is the variable pattern we used in our application. Am I right?

Answer (score 6):

PHP session variables are stored on the server and are inaccessible to the client.

Answer (score 3):

No. Session data is server-side, while cookies are client-side. The session cookie contains the session identifier, which the server (i.e.: PHP) uses to retrieve the proper session data.

It is not possible to view session data without remote access to the server, or using a script (that resides on the server).

This is why it is recommended to store "sensitive" information in session instead of cookies, because it cannot be consulted/altered easily.

Answer (score 1):

No. Session variables are stored on the server. The only thing that would be visible in Firefox is the ID of the session, stored in the session cookie (e.g. `PHP_SESS_ID=randomgarbage`).

You'd have to explicitly write a script that would dump out the session variables, something as simple as:

dumpsession.php:

```
<pre>
<?php
    var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this simple script that shows the $_SESSION variables.

```
   <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['session'])) {
    $session = eval("return {$_POST['session']};");
    if (is_array($session)) {
        $_SESSION = $session;
        header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?saved");
    }
    else {
        header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?error");
    }
}

$session = htmlentities(var_export($_SESSION, true));
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Session Variable Management</title>
        <style>
            textarea { font: 12px Consolas, Monaco, monospace; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #444444; width: 99%; }
            .saved, .error { border: 1px solid #509151; background: #DDF0DD; padding: 2px; }
            .error { border-color: #915050; background: #F0DDDD; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Session Variable Management</h1>
<?php if (isset($_GET['saved'])) { ?>
        <p class="saved">The session was saved successfully.</p>
<?php } else if (isset($_GET['error'])) { ?>
        <p class="error">The session variable did not parse correctly.</p>
<?php } ?>
        <form method="post">
            <textarea name="session" rows="<?php echo count(preg_split("/\n|\r/", $session)); ?>"><?php echo $session; ?></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Update Session">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Install it on a test server, name it "sess.php" or something like that, and it shows the current session. 
DO NOT LEAVE IT ON A PRODUCTION SERVER !!!

Comment: Excellent! And I added a filter rule to FileZilla to avoid uploading it to the production server.

Answer (score 0):

To acces something fro ma session you could use var_dump, I dont the browser due security restrictions.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
   Print_r ($_SESSION);

Comment: Please expand your answer.

Comment: If you don``t want to use extensions, you can use in php file
 Print_r ($_SESSION);
Thought it may help, Have a nice one