# PHP Session variable not working on multiple pages

Tags: php, session

I am new to working with PHP sessions.

To test code using $_SESSION I have created 2 test pages(`test_session.php`, `get_session_test.php`).  I have written this code using articles on w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_sessions.asp

The session variables are correctly set, I have used `print_r($_SESSION)` on the test_session.php page which shows they have been set as in the code.  However when I view the second page get_session_test.php no session variables are shown.  I have even tried the print_r($_SESSION) and this only shows an empty array: `Array ()`

in test_session.php the print_r shows `[favcolor] => green [favanimal] => cat` but in get_session_test.php no data shows

Here is the code on both pages:

test_session.php

```
<?php

    session_start();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

      <body>

    <?php

    $_SESSION["favcolor"]="green";
    $_SESSION["favanimal"]="cat";

    echo "Session variables are set";


        print_r($_SESSION);
        echo '<BR><BR>';
        echo $_SESSION["session_id"];
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

get_session_test.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>




<?php

print_r($_SESSION);

echo '<BR>';
echo '<BR>';


echo 'Favourite color is'.$_SESSION["favcolor"].'<BR>';
echo 'Favourite color is'.$_SESSION["favanimal"].'<BR>';

?>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: so in both test_session which has 3 echo's and get_test_session which has 2 echo's, none of the echo's print?

Comment: What environment are you in? Is this on a webhost? LAN server?

Comment: thanks @JurickPastechiGenaro - in test_session.php the print_r shows [favcolor] => green [favanimal] => cat but in get_session_test no data shows

Comment: thanks @GrumpyCrouton - I am testing this on the internet using a basic shared hosting account with iPage

Comment: Your code is completely valid, and works on my webhost. I suspect this has to do with a configuration setting somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session data working on local but not on ipage server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338747/session-data-working-on-local-but-not-on-ipage-server)

Comment: thanks @GrumpyCrouton ! - sorry about the duplicated post.  I shall test my code on the localhost/ i have set up on my computer.  I will probably now contact iPage to sort this out...

Comment: @JC Buckingham the reason i asked is because your code looks fine for me, and it works on my localhost. Are you using xamp, wamp or iis?

Comment: @JCBuckingham No problem at all, in fact this is one of those rare "good" duplicate posts. The wording for the question I linked you made it so you couldn't have found it easily, but now this post will likely link to the duplicate that I marked. Making more links to that post allows it to be an even better answer/question.

Comment: @JurickPastechiGenaro Read the other comments mate, that has already been answered. :)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton  after i commented i saw like 6 other comments appear, i was a bit late so my bad! :(

Comment: @JurickPastechiGenaro You're fine ^.^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View php session variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383270/view-php-session-variables)